# Set default gateway based on protocol using pfSense

Tags: smtp, pfsense, policy-routing

I have a pfSense configured with two Internet links for broadband load balancing.

One of these links block outgoing traffic on 25 port (WAN1). I have a mail server (IP 10.6.9.2) that should use the gateway of the internet without blocking (WAN2) when the destination port is 25 (SMTP).

We can do this setup with pfSense?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you've figured this out already, but the way to do that is through firewall rules with a specific gateway chosen. In pfSense and in general, this is called [Policy Based Routing or Policy Routing](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/What_is_policy_routing), so try searching for those terms if you have specific issues.

Answer (score 1):

I created the following firewall rule (Firewall > Rules) before the rule of the loadbalancer gateway:

`Protocol: *
Source: 10.6.9.2    Port: *
Destination: *    Port: 25 (SMTP)
Gateway: WAN2_GW`